# find file read it and search for specific identifier

Tags: linux, grep, find, cat

I'm trying to find out in what files some specific identifiers are being used. I know the file's name and know the identifier, therefore I use the following command to achieve my desired result:

```
find ./ -name "configuration.php" -print | xargs cat | grep db_userXYZ
```

The only issue is that, I'm losing the file name. I see that `db_userXYZ` is being used somewhere, but the command above, does not tell me in which file. The output would be something like:

```
$this->db_user = 'db_userXYZ';
$this->db_name = 'db_XYZ';
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
find ./ -name "configuration.php" -exec grep db_userXYZ /dev/null {} +
```

POSIX defined [find](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) `-exec  utility_name  [argument ...]   {} +`:

> If the primary expression is punctuated by a plus sign, the primary
>   shall always evaluate as true, and the pathnames for which the primary
>   is evaluated shall be aggregated into sets. The utility utility_name
>   shall be invoked once for each set of aggregated pathnames. Each
>   invocation shall begin after the last pathname in the set is
>   aggregated, and shall be completed before the find utility exits and
>   before the first pathname in the next set (if any) is aggregated for
>   this primary, but it is otherwise unspecified whether the invocation
>   occurs before, during, or after the evaluations of other primaries. If
>   any invocation returns a non-zero value as exit status, the find
>   utility shall return a non-zero exit status. An argument containing
>   only the two characters "{}" shall be replaced by the set of
>   aggregated pathnames, with each pathname passed as a separate argument
>   to the invoked utility in the same order that it was aggregated. The
>   size of any set of two or more pathnames shall be limited such that
>   execution of the utility does not cause the system's {ARG_MAX} limit
>   to be exceeded. If more than one argument containing only the two
>   characters "{}" is present, the behavior is unspecified.

If your `grep` supports `-H` option (`-H` is not defined by [POSIX grep](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)), you can use:

```
find ./ -name "configuration.php" -exec grep -H db_userXYZ {} +
```

Comment: oh, that's why I got the same output with `-exec grep db_userXYZ {} \;` Any idea where I can learn the difference between those two?

Comment: @w0rldart: You can read more here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html